# Issue with recursive tree traversal in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, tree

I am having tree structure data in the following format:

```
H1    
    H1 - 1
        H1 - 1 - 1
            H1 - 1 - 1 - 1
                H1 - 1 - 1 - 1 -1
                    H1 - 1 - 1 - 1 -1 - 1
        H1 - 1 - 2
        H1 - 1 - 3
    H1 - 2
        H1 - 2 - 1
        H1 - 2 - 2

H2    
H3    
    H3 - 1
        H3 - 1 - 1
            H3 - 1 - 1 - 1
                H3 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
            H3 - 1 - 1 - 2
        H3 - 1 - 2
        H3 - 1 - 3
    H3 - 2
```

I have to check if an item exists anywhere in the above tree by passing `ID` of the child item, so I need to traverse through each and every item in the above tree. I have written the following recursive method so far:

```
public bool CheckIfChildItemExists(Item parentItem, long childItemId)
{
    var isChildExisting = false;
    foreach (Item item in parentItem.Children)
    {
        if (item == context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault() || item.Children.Contains(context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()))
        {
            isChildExisting = true;
            return isChildExisting;
        }
        else
        {
            return CheckIfChildItemExists(item, childItemId);
        }
    }
    return isChildExisting;
}
```

Using the above method:

- Root items `H1, H2, H3` are accessible.
- All branches of `H1` (`H1 -1`, `H1 - 1 - 1`, `H1 - 1 - 1 -1`  etc.) are accessible.
- `H1 - 2 - 1` and `H1 - 2 - 2` are not accesible, they are not being traversed through. Their parent item `H1 - 2` is accessible though.
- All childs of `H3` are not accessible.

What am I doing wrong in my method?

Comment: Looks like you have List<Parents> not single root/parent, you have to handle this case.

Comment: @HariPrasad i have to check if the item exists in children of the `parentItem` which I am passing to method which is having the child data i have mentioned in the question. `H1, H2, H3` are child items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning to early. What you do is actually check in at most one branch from root to a leaf, but you never check other branches.

```
public bool CheckIfChildItemExists(Item parentItem, long childItemId)
{
    foreach (Item item in parentItem.Children)
    {
        if (item == context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault() || item.Children.Contains(context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var childItemExists = CheckIfChildItemExists(item, childItemId);
            if(childItemExists) return true; // else continue search in other children
        }
    }
    return isChildExisting;
}
```

I am not sure however you are having right condition in `if` statement. If all your items are are eligible for being searched in  you can try using the code. You should run this procedure for every root item or have an artificial root item to pass to the function.

```
public bool CheckIfChildItemExists(Item parentItem, long childItemId)
{
    if(parentItem.ItemID == childItemId && parentItem.IsActive) return true;
    foreach (Item item in parentItem.Children)
    {
        var childItemExists = CheckIfChildItemExists(item, childItemId);
        if(childItemExists) return true; // else continue search in 
    }
    return false;
}
```

In `item == context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()` you are actually comparing two objects, why not just check conditions against `item` object? Besides you can use `context.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive)` instead.

Comment: I have added `item == context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == childItemId && x.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()` condition to check if the current `Item` in the loop is the `ChidItem` we are searching for, if i remove this condition then the root level parents `H1, H2, H3` are getting skipped and only their children are traversed through if the `ChildItem` being searched for is of  `H1, H2 or H3`.

Comment: Try to get rid of checking if the children/grandchildren of current node satisfy condition. It is a job of a recursion to do it separately for each of the nodes.